# Spring retry without spring application

Tags: java, spring-retry

I have a java application, which starts from the main class (not Spring boot application). And I want to use Spring retry to retry when a connection is lost.
As I know I need to add @EnableRetry annotation above main class in Spring application and then use @Retryable above my method with retrying. But I think it will not work in the non-spring application.
 Is it possible to use spring retry in simple java application (not spring app)?

Comment: go through https://www.nexsoftsys.com/articles/how-to-integrate-spring-retry-in-java-application.html

Comment: Not in any simple since, but you can use resilience4j directly.

Comment: @F.K.M.N The link is about how to use in the spring application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that I can use RetryTemplate:

```
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2000l);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

    retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Void, Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public Void doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Throwable {
                // do some job
                if(context.getRetryCount() < 3){ // unexpected disconnection
                    log.error("connection failed");
                    throw new RuntimeException("retry exception"); 
                }
                System.out.println("RETRY" + context);
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Valerity - Can you please guide here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115536/spring-retry-doesnt-works-when-we-use-retrytemplate ?