# Spring Retry in non-spring apps?

Tags: java, spring

I was wondering if Spring Retry framework can be used in a regular Java application?
I'd like to use the retry framework in a legacy non-Spring application.

Can this be done? I've seen most of the articles online talking about using it in a Spring/Spring Boot application.

If it can be, are there any examples of using it?

Thanks..

Comment: Similar question was answered before. Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299658/spring-retry-without-spring-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299658/spring-retry-without-spring-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry and I made a small example project which shows you can use it outside of Spring based applications.